# Dropdown No Longer Works

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

This Dropdown suddenly stopped working. The Dir has not changed and the path should be OK. I am hoping a fresh set of eyes may catch something I'm not seeing. Thanks in advance.

```
  <select name="itinerarypath" type="text" id="itinerarypath">
          <option name="itinerarypath" type="text" id="itinerarypath" value="<?php echo $values['itinerarypath'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $values['itinerarypath'] ?></option>
      <?php 
           foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../uploads/*') as $filename){
           $filetypes = array("pdf", );
            $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {
                 $filename = basename($filename);
           echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";}
        }
    ?>

    </select>
```

Comment: if you are sure about the path and there are no errors in your page and not just showing the files in the drop down, then it's because id a missing `slash` in this line: `foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../uploads/*') as $filename){` and it should be like this: `foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../uploads/*') as $filename){`

Answer (score 0):

As EhsanT said I was just missing the backslash

```
<select name="itinerarypath" type="text" id="itinerarypath">
          <option name="itinerarypath" type="text" id="itinerarypath" value="<?php echo $values['itinerarypath'] ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $values['itinerarypath'] ?></option>
      <?php 
           foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../uploads/*') as $filename){
           $filetypes = array("pdf", );
            $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {
                 $filename = basename($filename);
           echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";}
        }
    ?>

    </select>
```